# How to perform an index shift on $\sum_{n\geq 2}(n+1)z^n$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I want to solve recurrence relation using generating functions. One part is $$\sum_{n\geq 2}(n+1)z^n$$
I know that there is a generating function for $$\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)z^n$$ so I need to shift the index (I guess?)
First I start with $$z^2\sum_{n\geq 2}(n+1)z^{(n-2)}$$

But how do I Index-Shift correctly?

My first idea would have been something like: $$z^2\bigg(\Big(\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)z^n\Big) -1-2z\bigg) = z^2\bigg(\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}-1-2z\bigg)$$
Substracting the parts for n=0 and n=1. But I have no idea if I can really do it like that.

Can anyone help me? (Confirm or show how to do it better)

The whole assignment is for: $a_n=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+n+1, n\geq2, a_0=1,a_1=4$

Comment: Hint:$$\sum_{n\ge2}(n+1)z^n=-1-2z+\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)z^n$$

Comment: just as @PeterForeman wrote, don't use an index shift, but add and subtract the missing terms such that you start with $n=0$.